# Prove that $\ln$ has an inverse function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, logarithms

For $x$ in $(0, \infty)$ let $\ln(x) =  \int_{1}^{x}\frac{1}{t}dt$. 
Prove that $\ln$ has an inverse function

My book does not really go into how to prove something has an inverse, besides it needing to be one-to-one. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: It is strictly increasing.

Answer (score 0):

Use the fundamental theorem of calculus to conclude that $\ln '(x)=1/x$. Since $x$ is positive, what does it say about (the graph of) the function $\ln (x)$? Can such a function not have an inverse?